# Workaround for :has in Firefox (not using JavaScript)

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-class

I am working on a small website for a friend of mine and am using the `:has` pseudo class. However, I know that there is no support on Firefox (unless someone has turned the flag on) so is there a workaround?

Essentially I am coding a hamburger menu but for use by people without JavaScript (80% of the intended audience disable JavaScript - long story) and I don't want to use span. Having watched a video from Web Dev Simplified I saw the use of `input["checkbox"]` but, without the `:has` pseudo class available, I'm a bit stuck.

I tried just using something like `input:checked::before` to adjust the top bar and `input:checked::after` for the bottom (to rotate on clicks) but this failed miserably!

Comment: `::before` or `::after` [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) can't be used on [Replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)   Read the doc !  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:has` pseudo-class is not supported in Firefox at the moment.
In this case, you can try sibling selectors such as `+` or `~`.

For example :

```
HTML :

<input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
<label for="menu-toggle">&#9776;</label>
<nav id="menu">
   // menu items
</nav>

CSS :

#menu {
  display: none;
}

#menu-toggle:checked + label + #menu {
  display: block; /* Can show menus if checkbox is checked */
}
```

You can build your CSS file according to your specific design and requirements.